# Blogger or Wordpress? Which suits for JS and its library?

Tags: user-interface, blogs, javascript

I'm currently developing a blog from blogger. I want to integrate the UI with JavaScript and its library. Do any obe have the experience. I've successfully implemented Syntax highlighter, but, need help for JS? How do you interact third party libraried like JQuery to your blog?

---

Further, What about Wordpress? Which is easy for my above requirement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have in mind that blogger is a closed hosted solution. So, even though it's quick to setup, you're not going to be able to customize it as much. Wordpress on the other hand is an open source CMS, you can download it, put it on a server and do with it whatever you want. You might also prefer to post this type of questions to [webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com). People over there will be able to help you better.